# mp3 file upload in php

Tags: php

When I am uploading mp3 file and then printing file array after submitting form it looks like this.

```
[file] => Array
        (
            [name] => tyu.mp3
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )
```

Can anyone please tell why `[error]` is set to `1` ?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: It shows an error occurred. Do you have any other information, such as, your error log?

Comment: In the file array ['error'] = 1. so i am not able to upload the mp3 file. and this problem occure only in mp3 file.

Comment: I'm currently using this is in core php so i don't have any error log.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 3):

Please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Error = 1 -  UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE - The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

You must increase upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Comment: ya..that was the problem, i have increased upload_max_filesize from php.ini and now it's working fine. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're asking what this means:
I means, that something went wrong while uploading the file.
What exactly went wrong, I cannot say from this piece of information alone.

Additional information from: http://www.php.net/manual/de/features.file-upload.errors.php
1 means: File too large

Please check your PHP.ini file.

Comment: In html file i'm writing like this                                <form action = "new.php" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="file" id="file" />" <input type = "submit" value = "submit" name = "submit" />and when in new.php writing like "print_r($_FILES)". so it's showing output as "[file] => Array ( [name] => tyu.mp3 [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) for mp3 file.

Comment: Yes, that's the HTML part. If it was incorrect, you wouldn't get this error, but rather an HTML error of some sort.